# How do I check Json array if it contains specific value?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

How do I check Json array if it contains specific value?

This is code in which I load the data:

```
 dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

 Console.WriteLine(d.number);
 Console.WriteLine(d.str);
 Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
 //this does not work
 d.array.Contains(1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use `ToObject` to convert the `JArray` to a list for you to use `Contain` method.,

```
d.array.ToObject<List<int>>().Contains(1)
```