# JArray.Contains returns false

Tags: c#, json.net

Why does `JArray.Contains` always returns `false`, what am I doing wrong ?

```
var array = JArray.Parse("['abc', 'aaa']");
Console.WriteLine("1: " + array.Contains("abc"));           // false
Console.WriteLine("2: " + array.Contains((JToken)"abc"));   // false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check Json array if it contains specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074470/how-do-i-check-json-array-if-it-contains-specific-value)

Comment: Unfortunately, `JArray.Contains` only searches for `JToken` instances, not their values. You'll notice that if you search for `array[0]`, it says `True` because it found the exact instance you searched for. You will have to either use a LINQ pattern with a predicate, or convert the JArray to a `List<string>` and search that instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JArray.Contains issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343771/jarray-contains-issue)

Comment: Oh, i thought it works just like linq, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Contains` rely on `IndexOf` then `IndexOfItem` then `IndexOfReference` which use `ReferenceEquals` (the code is [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/bf2e2a78e8febf0006ec647f9bde3aa5bbe0ce72/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/CollectionUtils.cs#L242-L253)).

Since the calls to `Contains` implicitly create new `JToken` references, those references are different and the function return `false`

If you call `Contains` with a reference that is actually in the array, it will return `true`:

```
var array = JArray.Parse("['abc', 'aaa']");
var first = array[0];

Console.WriteLine("1: " + array.Contains("abc"));           // false
Console.WriteLine("2: " + array.Contains((JToken)"abc"));   // false
Console.WriteLine("3: " + array.Contains(first));           // true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var array = JArray.Parse("['abc', 'aaa']");
var data = array.Any(x => x.Value<string>() == "abc");
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Comment: this does not answer to the "why"

Comment: how is it not responding you are doing the code wrong
var array = JArray.Parse("['abc', 'aaa']");
var data = array.Any(x => x.Value<string>() == "abc");
Console.WriteLine(data);

Comment: Basically here what you are doing:
*Q: Why my car doesn't start?*, *A: Just take a taxi.*

Comment: Maybe the answer doesn't tell why the given code doesn't work, but the code in the answer solved my problem, so I +1ed this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Orace has brilliantly deduced, the comparison by reference negates the usefulness of `.Contains`.  However, I believe behind your question is the desire to actually perform a Contains on the array.  My solution is ugly, but I take the extra step to convert the `JArray` to `List<string>`, like this:

```
var tmparray = JArray.Parse("['abc', 'aaa']");
var array = tmparray.ToObject<List<string>>();

if (array.Contains("aaa"))
{
   ...
}
```